# How to read a .csv file embeded in a Word file

Tags: vba, ms-word

I currently am working on an MS Word form where I use VBA to import data from a .csv file. The form is a phone request for employes who work outside, and my .csv is a list of phones that is updated for time to time. My boss would like to have this .csv directly into the Word to have only one single file to handle.

I found how to include (embeded) it, I go to "insert" tab on the ribbon, "Object" button, then "Create from File" tab. I check "display as icon" but not "Link to file".

My .csv is only used to import data through a macro when opening the Word form. Data are then paste in a variable that is handled in VBA to fill combos. The .csv is periodicaly updated and re-embedded so the form is updated also. I don't plan to alter the .csv in VBA in any way.

The objective is eventualy to give the Word document to someone else who will embed a new .csv when needed, but won't look at the code.

The problem I am working on is to reach the .csv and  import data.

Another solution, thanks to @Cindy Meister's and @SlowLearner's comments for pointing out the idea, would be to use Custom XML Parts. I will make some additional researches about that.

Moreover, with my currently very limited experience on programming and VBA, I'm not sure how to handle that (I'm not even sure it's possible). The lack of quality documentation on VBA doesn't help either.

After comments of @Cindy Meister and @SlowLearner, I reformulated part of the question to be more precise, although I feel it's getting very long and and messy. I probably should make my own research to narrow down the problem.

ps: that's my first question here, so any advice is welcome, and please be nice with me :)

Comment: I'm going to try to be nice :-) But do please take a moment to read the guidelines for what can / should not be asked on Stack Overflow in the [help] - your question is "too broad". That said, I recommend you look at the concept of **Custom XML Parts**. That would be the "correct" way to carry data within a document. An alternative would be to write the CSV content to a **Document Variable** - this is internal storage in Word for string content and has been available in Word since the beginning (1990 or s0). It can usually handle quite a bit of data and you might find it simpler to work with.

Comment: You have been really kind, thank you very much :) Yeah, I felt when I wrote my question it may not be very well formulated. Although it is clear in my mind, it is not easy to write it down. Anyway, thank you for your suggest, I will dig this way.

Comment: About your question: One very important thing that's missing is HOW the csv is embedded. That's not something normally done in Word, so it would be pure guess work to even begin to formulate an answer to your question. You might want to edit that information in...

Comment: There are many approaches to this, as @CindyMeister said embedding a CSV file might not be the best way forward. You can convert CSV to XML (https://www.google.com.au/search?q=convert+csv+to+xml) and may find some useful code on Greg Maxey site to get you started, e.g: https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/customXML_helpful_help.html & https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/tinkering_with_CustomXMLParts.html